# The '0' in GET response. what does that mean?

Tags: html, client, telnet, zero

I tried this in my ubuntu telnet client:

```
> telnet www.google.com 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
```

What I got back is a bunch of HTML lines in the console. 
I noticed one thing at the end of the last line, right after closing tag /Script.
There is a character '0' ... what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of file, EOF.

Answer (score 5):

At the start of the response you will see:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

1000
```

HTTP [chunked transfer encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-3.6.1) means that the server doesn't know in advance how big the `Content-Length` of the response is going to be, so it'll give you it a bit at a time. This type of response is typical for server-side scripts, when the web server wants to start sending back script results to the user before the script has completely finished.

So the `1000` is a sign that there's a block of 4096 (0x1000) bytes to follow: `<!doctype html><html><head><meta...`. After 1000 bytes you get another chunk header saying (in my request) `f65`, meaning 3941 more bytes. After that, `cc0` (3264 more bytes) and finally `0` which is a signal that the response is complete.